# Spawned objects don't show on the surface of the position i wanted them to show

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script where i click and spawn objects out of the bushes. the problem is when the Item is spawned which is shown in the heirarchy as (Clone) doesn't show in play mode can't see it anywhere.

this is the picture of the play mode:

[image: Spawning objects do not show in game]

and this is the script for the spawning objects i don't know if i'm doing something wrong in randomizing the position:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomObjectSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] myObjects;



    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))

        {

            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, myObjects.Length - 1);
            Vector3 randomSpawnPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10, 11), 5, Random.Range(-10, 11));

            Instantiate(myObjects[randomIndex], randomSpawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
             
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the spawned objects are also Canvas Objects. So you have to set the parent to somewhere inside the canvas.

This can be done directly with the instantiate method. You can add the transform of the parent as a fourth parameter for your Instantiate method.

To do that add `public Transform groupTransform;` in your `RandomObjectSpawner` class. Change your Instantiate line to:

```
Instantiate(myObjects[randomIndex], randomSpawnPosition, Quaternion.identity, groupTransform);
```

Then in the Editor drag your Group Gameobject to the groupTransform field on the `RandomObjectSpawner` script.

Comment: my objects are inside a GameObject Group i put them there to keep them all together grouped.

Comment: but the clone item in the image is not inside the canvas right?

Comment: yeah its not you're right how do i spawn it inside the canvas?

Comment: You can put the gameobject group inside the canvas, and then pass the transform of this object into your instantiate function.

Comment: my group of items is inside the canva already it's just the clones are going out of it. so i will try to fix that from the script. thank you so much!

Comment: Any idea how to pass that group into the instantiate function because i don't know how to do that.

Comment: I extended my answer